# Split each line of a dataframe and turn into excel file - 'list' object has no attribute 'to_frame error'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and want to create an excel file for each row on that dataframe.

what am I missing?

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'] , 'col2': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

b=[]

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    content = b.to_frame().T
    content.to_excel("file number" + str(i))
```

Comment: should it be `content = row.to_frame().T`?

Comment: `b` is just an empty list?

Comment: if i dont create an empty list on b is shows b is not defined error

Comment: `for index, row in df.iterrows() ; row.T.to_excel(f"file number {index}.xlsx",index=False)` should fix your issue

Comment: if i use  content = row.to_frame().T it shows  Error ''No engine for filetype: ''

Comment: @TiagoEmanuelPratas it is because you don't specify the file extension `.xlsx` in the file name at the next line of code

Comment: thank you very much for the help guys !

Answer (score 0):

First, b is a empty list. You must insert a value on it, before use b.to_frame().T

Maybe b=row
Or, just use row instead of b (see the example below)

Second, you need put ".xlsx" in the end of the excel file.

For instance:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'] , 'col2':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    content = row.to_frame().T
    content.to_excel("file number" + str(i) + '.xlsx')
```